# Django middleware find content type in response

Tags: json, django, response, wrapper, middleware

I am looking to write middleware to modify response object that is generated by rest framework - JSON format.

I want to add to each JSON response some so called envelope that would wrap data object to something like:

```
{
   "status" : "success",
   "server" : "server name",
   "source" : "cache", -- or "database"
   "data" : ... original response from API ...
   "errors" : [],
   ect ....    
}
```

I was thinking about creating middleware that would look for 'application/json' content and if yes capture response wrap it in that object but not react if other types 'application/text'

How I can access to content type in `process_response` method in middleware ?

And is it proper way to do such tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware's [`process_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_response) method takes two arguments, `request` and `response` object.

In the method you can check the content type with `response['Content-Type']`.